# My deployed Vue app works locally but not on remote server

Tags: vue.js, webpack, deployment

After doing `npm run build` I uploaded `index.html` and the `dist` folder to my remote server yet the app doesn't work properly: there's no styles at all, routes don't work and most UI elements don't load.

Strangely, the exact same `index.html` + `dist` folder, copied anywhere on my local server, works perfectly either as `file` protocol or `http` protocol.

I have no idea what to make of this and I can't troubleshoot it because there's no error message in the console even though the app doesn't work. Any suggestion welcome.

Note: I use `vue-cli` / `webpack-simple`

Comment: Any chance to take a look into your code?Also it may be a problem related to your server.

Comment: Did you configured your remote server in order to serve SPA app?

Comment: @Vladislav Ladicky: I don't control the remote server, it's a cheap hosting provider package. I can't find any info online on whether a hosting package can be SPA compatible or not. It looks like any server can run a SPA, at least with commercial providers? If not please provide input

Comment: And this your provider is running Apache web server?

Answer (score 0):

If your provider is running Apache web server, upload to the same directory you uploaded your SPA app the .htaccess file with this content:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule (.*) index.html [QSA,L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I can't do that because at the root directory I have my WordPress website running... And yes it IS an Apache server.

Comment: So, where, to what subdirectory in root directory you uploaded your SPA?

Comment: Well in the root directory I created a subdirectory in which I uploaded my SPA.

Comment: Then just place this .htaccess file to this subdirectory, where your SPA lies.

Comment: Done. Doesn't change anything I'm afraid.

Comment: Really... Use phpinfo() and verify the mod_rewrite module is loaded.

Comment: It turns out the app works perfectly, it was Chrome's cache that was messing everything up. It's not the first time Chrome's cache makes me waste hours for nothing. What's wrong with that thing? Is there a way to tell Chrome to cache NOTHING EVER?

Comment: Two most complicated things in programming: 1. naming things, 2. invalidate cache :) Really, google for it... Mainly, it is completely bad idea. Cache is your friend, to speed up things. But yes, sometimes the invalidation is a nightmare.